# Error messages on Java code that has me make 2 calculator objects and perform operations on them

Tags: java, object

Here's the main Java file:

```
   class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Calculator One = new Calculator(100,50,"Addition");
   One.calculateNums();
   One.showResults();
   Calculator Two = new Calculator(100,50,"Subtraction");
   Two.changeNumOne("200");
   Two.calculateNums();
   Two.showResults();

  }
}
```

And here's the calculator java code:

```
public class Calculator {
  // instance variables - first number, second number, operation
  private int firstNum;
  private int secondNum;
  private String operation;

  // static field to keep track of number of Calculator objects
  public static int Calculatorobjects = 0;
  // default constructor
  public Calculator(){
    int firstNum = 0;
    int secondNum = 0;
    operation = "Addition";
  }
  // initializing constructor
  public Calculator(int firstNum, int secondNum, int NumOperation){
    NumOne = firstNum;
    NumTwo = secondNum;
    NumOperation = operation;
  }
  // getters for all 3 instance variables
  public int one(){
    return firstNum;
  }
  public int two(){
    return secondNum;
  }
  public String three(){
    return operation;
  }
  // setters to be able to change any of the 3 instance variables after creating them
  public void changeNumOne(int NewNumOne){
    firstNum = NewNumOne;
  }
  public void changeNumOne(int NewNumTwo){
    SecondNum = NewNumTwo;
  } 
  public void changeNumOne(String NewNumOperation){
    operation = NewNumOperation;
  }
  // instance method to perform operation
  public void calculateNums(int result){
    if(operation == "Addition"){
      result = firstNum + secondNum;
    }
    if(operation == "Subtraction"){
      result = firstNum - secondNum;
    }
  }
  // instance method to display results
  public void showResults(){
    System.out.println(firstNum + " " +  operation + " " + secondNum + " = " + result);
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error messages:

```
exit status 1
Calculator.java:35: error: method changeNumOne(int) is already defined in class Calculator
  public void changeNumOne(int NewNumTwo){
              ^
Calculator.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    SecondNum = NewNumTwo;
    ^
  symbol:   variable SecondNum
  location: class Calculator
Calculator.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(firstNum + " " +  operation + " " + secondNum + " = " + result);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable result
  location: class Calculator
Main.java:4: error: method calculateNums in class Calculator cannot be applied to given types;
   One.calculateNums();
      ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Main.java:8: error: method calculateNums in class Calculator cannot be applied to given types;
   Two.calculateNums();
      ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
5 errors
```

I've tried a bunch of random things while trying to fix it and all of them have either done nothing or made even more errors. I'm an amateur at Java so I definitely did a lot of things wrong but if someone could point them out and send the right code that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** At least you need to fix:

```
public void changeNumOne(int NewNumOne){
    firstNum = NewNumOne;
}

// Error: Same name as above
public void changeNumOne(int NewNumTwo){
    // Error: Capital SecondName
    SecondNum = NewNumTwo;
}
```

To:

```
public void changeNumOne(int firstNum){
    this.firstNum = firstNum;
}

public void changeNumTwo(int secondNum){
    this.secondNum = secondNum;
}
```

**2.)** And here you would like to print `result`, but your class does not have such a variable (also check, if your function `calculateNums` makes sense):

```
public void showResults(){
    System.out.println(firstNum + " " +  operation + " " + secondNum + " = " + result);
}
```

**3.)** This should also fail:

```
public Calculator(int firstNum, int secondNum, int NumOperation){
    NumOne = firstNum;
    NumTwo = secondNum;
    NumOperation = operation;
}
```

Should be:

```
public Calculator(int firstNum, int secondNum, string operation){
    this.firstNum = firstNum;
    this.secondNum = secondNum;
    this.operation = operation;
}
```

**4.)** Here you do not assign the values:

```
public Calculator(){
    int firstNum = 0;
    int secondNum = 0;
    operation = "Addition";
}
```

Should be:

```
public Calculator(){
    this.firstNum = 0;
    this.secondNum = 0;
    this.operation = "Addition";
}
```

**Overall:**

There might be other errors.

You need to check all your variables names. They are quite inconsistent. Though, read your error messages carefully and try to understand them for the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors. I solved with this code, acting with `Calculator` class. I commented on the code where there were errors.

```
class Calculator {
// instance variables - first number, second number, operation
private int firstNum;
private int secondNum;
private int result;   //I declare the result variable so I can print it
private String operation;

// static field to keep track of number of Calculator objects
public static int Calculatorobjects = 0;
// default constructor
public Calculator(){
    this.firstNum = 0;    //useless because uninitialized int are already 0
    this.secondNum = 0;     //same
    this.operation = "Addition";
}
// initializing constructor
public Calculator(int firstNum, int secondNum, String NumOperation){   //NumOperation is a String, not an int
    this.firstNum = firstNum;    //I'm setting the global variables as the local variables that you pass to the constructor
    this.secondNum = secondNum;
    this.operation = NumOperation;
}
// getters for all 3 instance variables
public int one(){
    return firstNum;
}
public int two(){
    return secondNum;
}
public String three(){
    return operation;
}
// setters to be able to change any of the 3 instance variables after creating them
public void changeNumOne(int NewNumOne){
    firstNum = NewNumOne;
}
public void changeNumTwo(int NewNumTwo){.   //changed method name
    secondNum = NewNumTwo;
}
public void changeNumOne(String NewNumOperation){
    operation = NewNumOperation;
}
// instance method to perform operation
public void calculateNums(){
    if(operation.equals("Addition")){     //equals is used to compare strings
        result = firstNum + secondNum;
    }
    if(operation.equals("Subtraction")){
        result = firstNum - secondNum;
    }
}
// instance method to display results
public void showResults(){
    System.out.println(firstNum + " " +  operation + " " + secondNum + " = " + result);
}
```